# Android - why is this telling me "Content view not yet created"?

Tags: android, android-listview

This is a populating a listview on a fragment from a database:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            LinearLayout Layout5 = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag5_layout, container, false);

            Cursor allBands;
            MyDatabase db;

            Context ctx = (Context)TabFragment5.this.getActivity();


            db = new MyDatabase(ctx);
            allBands = db.getBands();


            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (ctx, 
                    R.layout.listelement, 
                    allBands, 
                    new String[] {"BandName"},  
                    new int[] {R.id.text15});

            getListView().setAdapter(adapter);  

            return Layout5;

         }
```

Why is this giving me the  "Content view not yet created" On logcat? the program forces close when the fragment opens...

Comment: Shouldn't be first statement setContentView(..)?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm working with fragments.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I solved it by moving the adapter and the getListview to onActivityCreated(...).

onCreateView just inflates and returns the layout.

Comment: When you call setAdapter(), the ListFragment checks to ensure there is a list defined in your layouts and since onCreateView() hasn't given the fragment its view, it's a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: Do both setAdapter() and getListView() the ensure checking? I'm sure about getListView(), but not about setAdapter()

Comment: why not onViewCreated.  it seems to be the most intuitive option.

Answer (score 2):

A `Fragment` should usually put inside an `Activity` while the `onCreateView()` will contribute the layout of `Fragment` to its container `Activity`.

Quoted from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html

> A fragment is usually used as part of an activity's user interface and
>   contributes its own layout to the activity.

So, the problem may probably be caused by the missing of `setContentView()` in your container `Activity` instead of your `Fragment`.

Comment: Please read the folloup to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297151/android-why-is-this-happening-content-not-yet-created-error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but my fault was to call a (invisible) fragment from a background task via an interface. so the invisible fragment tried to use its view which was not available... i fixed it with the same solution: the interface function checks if fragment isVisible(). 
Thank you for showing me the right direction...

```
 public void updateListInterface(){
    if(this.isVisible()) {
        this.initListAdapter();
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
    } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "view is not visible");
    }
}
```