# ListFragment how to get the listView?

Tags: java, android

I'm porting my app from AsyncTasks to Fragements.

But how can I access the listView (id: list) element within my fragment?

```
class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_fragment, container, false);
        ListView listView = getListView(); //EX: 
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        return v;
    }
}
```

xml:

```
        <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </ListView>
```

Ex:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286391/android-why-is-this-telling-me-content-view-not-yet-created

Answer (score 28, accepted):

as the `onCreateView` doc stays:

```
creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment
```

so since the method does not return, you will are not able to access the `ListView` through `getListView()`. You can obtain a valid reference in the `onActivityCreated` callback.
Or you can try using `v.findViewById(android.R.id.list)` if the `ListView` is declared inside `list_fragment.xml`

Comment: I use onActivityCreate and get the contentview not created crash, even with using a postdelayed method with 100 millisecond wait

Answer (score 7):

get list View from the view, you are getting earlier.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.list_content, null);
    ListView ls = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // do whatever you want to with list.
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and more reliable solution to this problem will be to override onActivityCreated(); and do your list manipulations there.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView listView = getListView(); //EX: 
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to access the ListView by the OnViewCreated method instead.

Comment: This seems like the most appropriate solution to me. According to <a href="http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onViewCreated%28android.view.View,%20android.os.Bundle%29">the docs</a>... `onViewCreated` is called immediately after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in to the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point.

Answer (score 1):

```
ListFragment listFrag = new ListFragment(){
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            ListView list = getListView();
            // DO THINGS WITH LIST
        }
    };
```