# Error: Content view not yet created

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development and I have a problem with setting up getting into the next activity when I click an item in my listview within my ListFragment.

When I compile and run the app, it crashes with the error: Content view not yet created. Here is the relevant code. Any help would be much appreciated!

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.szen95.meddict;


import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new SearchFragment())
                .commit();
    }

    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0f);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem( R.id.search_bar ).getActionView();

    searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo( getComponentName() ) );

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

SearchFragment:

```
package com.example.szen95.meddict;


/**
 * Created by szen95 on 6/15/15.
 */


import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class SearchFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // URL to get contacts JSON
    private static String url = "http://dailymed.nlm.nih.gov/dailymed/services/v2/drugclasses.json";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    private static final String TAG_CODE = "code";
    private static final String TAG_CODING_SYSTEM = "codingSystem";
    private static final String TAG_TYPE = "type";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";


    // contacts JSONArray
    JSONArray data = null;
//    ArrayAdapter<String> mConditionsAdapter;

    public SearchFragment() {
    }

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        dataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        // Creating view correspoding to the fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        ListView lv = getListView();

        // Listview on item click listener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String code = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code))
                        .getText().toString();

                // Starting single contact activity
                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        Details.class);
                in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_CODE, code);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });


        new GetData().execute();

        return v;
    }


    /**
     * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
     * */
    private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            //
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    data = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                        String code = c.getString(TAG_CODE);
                        String codingSystem = c.getString(TAG_CODING_SYSTEM);
                        String type = c.getString(TAG_TYPE);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);


                        // tmp hashmap for single contact
                        HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        data.put(TAG_CODE, code);
                        data.put(TAG_CODING_SYSTEM, codingSystem);
                        data.put(TAG_TYPE, type);
                        data.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding contact to contact list
                        dataList.add(data);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * */
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), dataList,
                    R.layout.list_item_search, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_CODE}, new int[] { R.id.name,
                    R.id.code});

            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
//
//    @Override
//    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
//        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
//
//
//    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
//            FetchDataTask defTask = new FetchDataTask();
//            defTask.execute();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Details:

```
package com.example.szen95.meddict;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;




public class Details extends ActionBarActivity {


// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_CODE = "code";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);

    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String name = in.getStringExtra(TAG_NAME);
    String code = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CODE);

    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);
    TextView lblCode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_label);

    lblName.setText(name);
    lblCode.setText(code);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    return onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at some of the answers to related questions, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286391/android-why-is-this-telling-me-content-view-not-yet-created)?

Comment: @qbix I looked at some related questions including that, but I can't get a solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: Can you post the code for the activity that uses SearchFragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SearchFragment extends ListFragment. In a ListFragment, `getListView()` cannot be called in `onCreateView()`, because `onCreateView()` is creating the fragment's content view and has not yet completed.  The call to `getListView()` in SearchFragment is the cause of the exception.

Move the the call to `getListView()` and related to code to one of the fragment lifecycle methods that is called after `onCreateView()`, such as `onViewCreated()` or `onActivityCreate()`.  For example:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String code = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                    Details.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CODE, code);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, I have done this and now my app compiles and runs. However, when I click an item in my listview, the app freezes but without any errors though.

Comment: You need to add more Log.d() statements to your code to enable you to see what it is doing.   For example, a Log statement in the onCreate() method of the Details activity will tell you if the activity is created. Check your AndroidManifest.xml file to make sure the Details activity is defined there.

Comment: Alright, I have added the the Log.d() statements like you suggested. However, I'm still getting the same problems though. I added them to the onCreate() method of the Details activity and the onItemClick() method in the SearchFragment. The messages both show up in my Logcat when I click an item. The Details activity is defined in my AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: If the Details activity gets created, I can't explain why you do not see its content.  When you say the "app freezes" do you mean that does not respond to any touch input?  Does the back button still work?  What do you do to end the app so you can run again?

Comment: Yes, the app doesn't respond to any touch input. The back button doesn't work and I have to close the app. When I click an item on the listview, I also get a dialog saying the app is unresponsive, prompting me to close the app.

Comment: I can't spend any more time on this.  I'm glad I was able to answer the question you posted.  I suggest that you resolve the remaining problems by adding Log statement and selectively disabling code to see what's working and what's not.  For example, in SearchFragment, comment out the call to startActivity() to see if you can successfully select items without lock up.  If so, restore the statement and disable things in Details activity, or add more Log statements to see how far you get in the processing.  With repeated experiments, you should be able to find the source of the lock up.

Comment: Alright, I shall keep experimenting then. Thank you for your time, it is much appreciated, especially since I'm completely new to the world of Android development.